# Xamarin.Forms.EntryCell: How to trigger the event while input any key

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a problem with Xamarin.Forms.EntryCell. I want to know how to trigger an event if the text of the `EntryCell` has changed. Not the event 'Completed', it is just triggered when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after inputting anything.

```
<EntryCell 
    Label="User Id" 
    x:Name="UserIdEntryCell" 
    HorizontalTextAlignment="End" 
    Completed="UserIdCompleted"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there is no event that is fired when the text is changed ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.entrycell?view=xamarin-forms#ereignisse)). Anyway, this does not mean that you can't achieve what you want, by means of `Text` property. Since you are using the event I do not assume that you use MVVM (you should really give it a try, though), hence we'll have to create a property we will bind the `EntryCell.Text` to in your view (I'm assuming a view, but for a page it would be quite similar)

In your code behind add a property `Text` that calls `HandleTextChanged` from its setter:

```
class MyView : ContentView
{
    string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            HandleTextChanged();
        }
    }

    private void HandleTextChange()
    {
        // do whatever you need to do
    }

}
```

You can bind this property to `EntryCell.Text` from your XAML

Now `MyView.Text` will be set every time the text in your `EntryCell` changes.